# In Graphviz, how to set only one edge to spline=curve

Tags: r, graphviz, dot

I am trying to draw a `lavaan` model using `Graphviz` and am happy in general with how it looks (1st graph), but would like the edge between the two dimensions to be curved but all the others to be straight.

Is it possible to get the edge between dimensions (edge `d1` to `d2`) to curve by specifying `graph [layout = neato, overlap = FALSE, outputorder = edgesfirst, splines = curved]`, as you can see in the second graph, but this makes all of them curved.

Could anyone guide me how to get the desired result?

Here is the code to reproduce the first graph:

```
grViz("
digraph CFA {
graph [layout = neato, overlap = FALSE, outputorder = edgesfirst]
node [shape = rectangle]
edge [arrowhead = vee]
# Nodes (variables)
m1 [pos = '-5,1.5!', label = 'VAR1']
m2 [pos = '-5,0.5!', label = 'VAR2']
m3 [pos = '-5,-0.5!', label = 'VAR3']
m4 [pos = '-5,-1.5!', label = 'VAR4']
d1 [pos = '-1.5,0!', label = 'Info', shape = ellipse, width=1]
d2 [pos = '1.5,0!', label = 'Support', shape = ellipse, width=1]
m5 [pos = '5,1.5!', label = 'VAR5']
m6 [pos = '5,0.5!', label = 'VAR6']
m7 [pos = '5,-0.5!', label = 'VAR7']
m8 [pos = '5,-1.5!', label = 'VAR8']
# Edges (loadings)
d1->m1 [label = '1']
d1->m2 [label = '0.82']
d1->m3 [label = '1.20']
d1->m4 [label = '0.70']
d2->m5 [label = '1']
d2->m6 [label = '0.89']
d2->m7 [label = '1.08']
d2->m8 [label = '1.15']
# Define Error
m1->m1 [label = '0.34', dir=both, tailport = 'sw', headport = 'nw', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m2->m2 [label = '0.45', dir=both, tailport = 'sw', headport = 'nw', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m3->m3 [label = '0.28', dir=both, tailport = 'sw', headport = 'nw', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m4->m4 [label = '0.98', dir=both, tailport = 'sw', headport = 'nw', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m5->m5 [label = '0.64', dir=both, tailport = 'se', headport = 'ne', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m6->m6 [label = '0.31', dir=both, tailport = 'se', headport = 'ne', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m7->m7 [label = '0.42', dir=both, tailport = 'se', headport = 'ne', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
m8->m8 [label = '0.25', dir=both, tailport = 'se', headport = 'ne', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
d1->d1 [label = '0.65', dir=both, tailport = 'se', headport = 'ne', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
d2->d2 [label = '0.72', dir=both, tailport = 'sw', headport = 'nw', arrowhead=curve, arrowtail=curve, style=dashed]
# Covariance
d1->d2 [label = '0.45', dir = both, arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=vee, splines=curved, tailport = 's', headport = 's']
}
")
```

And here are the plots:

First CFA plot with all edges straight

[image]

Second CFA plot with curved edges

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use a dummy node which we will try to curve the edge around (change the `height` to control the curve)

```
dummy [pos = '0,0!', height=1.5, label='', color=white]
```

Then you can set the correlation / curved edge with

```
d1:s->d2:s [label = '0.45', dir = both]
```

You will also need the `graph` option `splines=true`.

Adding these produces

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer; elegant, creative and well explained. Solved my problem perfectly.

Comment: You're welcome. In case it also suits your use case, I have generally moved to tikz / [dot2tex](https://dot2tex.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage_guide.html#output-formats) for these small graphs as I find it a bit easier for fine control.